# uninitialized constant PersonsController::Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, uninitialized-constant

I tried hard to find this exact match of my error but I am unable to do so. I am new to Ruby and stuck for long after this block. Please help.
I have checked my `route.rb` file my controller method `show` and my `show.html.erb` file  error remains.
I destroyed and created controller again and again to check but still the error remains.
Is it asking me to define/declare variable user?? have not I did so?? like in controller i did `@user` and then called databsae.. I think so.
Thanks in advance

The controller:

```
class PersonsController < ApplicationController

  def show
  @user = Users.find(params[:id])

  end
end
```

The view:

```
<%= provide(:title, @user.name %>
<h1> @user.name </h1>
<%=@user.name %>, <%=@user.email %>
```

The routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'persons/show'

  root 'staticpages#home'

  get 'help' => 'staticpages#help'

  get 'about' => 'staticpages#about'

  resources :persons
  resources :person

end
```

Comment: could you please paste the error text, also in the view you used `provide(:title, @user.name` , what is this for? also it's missing a bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Model names in Rails are singular:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: SyntaxError in PersonsController#show  now this error occured. these both are coming simultaneously :( @Marek Lipka

Comment: @usmanali you must have done something wrong with copy/pasting my snippet.

Comment: Sir @Marek Its okay down voting me. But it did not helped me at all. I copy pasted but error says.. 
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PersonsController#show
Where as I have used ruby console and debug to check record the user exists in table. Kindly help me getting out of this

Comment: What params do you pass into your controller?

Comment: BTW in my opinion you should spend some time on learning Ruby/Rails basics.

Comment: I tried passing 1 and my url is somehow /persons/1 and
I also tried /persons/show 
both  gave me errors

Comment: `/persons/show` won't work, that's why you should learn some basics at the beginning. `/persons/1` will work only if there is `User` record with id of 1. What does `/persons/1` call return? What does `User.find(1)` return in your console?

Comment: User.find('1')
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "hello sir", email: "hi@gmail.com", created_at: "2015-08-05 10:07:18", updated_at: "2015-08-05 10:07:18", password_digest: "$2a$10$C71U7KhTfb5d4CFOqecUm.v1xiqkToHsle0dXevYjLw...">


this is what my console says about User.find('1') @Marek

Comment: And what's the result of `/persons/1` call?

Comment: I bet it's syntax error. Instead of `<%= provide(:title, @user.name %>` you should have `<%= provide(:title, @user.name) %>`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Marek. yes I am learning. At times I am stuck  I seek for help fromk seniors.  Thanks and down voting blocks me frrom further asking :(

Comment: It's a good thing in my opinion - you should try to solve this kind of problems on your own before asking here.